# Generate a maze of accessible and inaccessible cells

Tags: algorithm, maze

I need to generate a small maze — a grid of accessible and inaccessible cells. For example (if 0 is accessible and 1 is not):

```
0011
1011
1000
1110
```

I've found a lot of algorithms for creating mazes, but they're all for mazes of a different type (namely, mazes where there are walls *between* certain cells, rather than mazes where some cells are *themselves* walls).

I tried just randomly moving and adding walls, but than I ran into dead ends. So I used a stack to be able to come back and try an other branch. I was still running in to dead ends, so I decided to generate several mazes and take a valid one.

```
****
111*
****
*111
***1
01**
```

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Start with all zero-cells.  Select random zero-cell and change it to one-cell, repeat while maze beginning is connected to maze end.

Comment: What is the problem with "removing walls between cells" ?

Why doesn't it match your problem ?

Comment: See what I wrote here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37784451/3045171 . Run some code to generate a graph from the data that you have. Cells become nodes, and edges exist only between cells that are "neighbors".

Comment: @OB1 To remove the walls, I first need to set them, how?

Comment: you also can define some patterns, and mix them randomly